How should I put NOPs in RISC-V code snippet?
Consider this short RISC-V snippet pipelined
add x15,x12,11
ld x13,4(x15)
ld x12,0(x2)
or x13,x15,x13
sd x13,0(x15)`

The exercise asks to insert NOP where necessary to do not have any hazard or problems during the execution ( no re-order of the code )
Considering all RISC-V pipeline phases ( IF - ID - EXE - MEM - WB )
My possible solution is to add those NOP
add x15,x12,11
nop
nop
ld x13,4(x15)
ld x12,0(x2)
or x13,x15,x13
nop
nop
sd x13,0(x15)`

Could it be ok?
And my other question was considering a hazard/dependency like in the first two instruction, the second one can start only when the first one is in the WB phase exactly? So 2 NOPS are more than ok?

WB and ID can overlap and still get the up-to-date, newly written value in ID.  Thus, only 2 nops are needed.  If WB and ID could not overlap, that is to say, ID would still get a stale value, then 3 nops would be needed.
